# simple and compound annual investment calculator in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a simple compound and annual investment calculator, but there is an error that I have been unable to spot. Am I missing a for or while loop?

```
investment=float(input("Enter an initial investment."))
interest=float(input("Enter an interest rate between .01 to .10."))
years=float(input("Enter a number of years between 1 to 30."))

t=(investment) * (interest+1) ** (years)
print(t)
```

Comment: what is your _exact_ problem? We do not code for you, we help you out... I can not see a problem.

Comment: Oh Imight see one- you need to calculat the years and print them, not only print to last value. a `for y in range(years):` (and years being an int) should make this possible. Have fun solving it.

Comment: are you dealig with simple or compound?

Comment: @Onyambu out teacher did not say but I think both.

Comment: @PatrickArtner It gives me a completely random number that I am pretty sure is not accurate. I have not been able to find the problem in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers look good to me .... (`1000` + `.01` + `10`):

```
def formatInterest(t):
    return "{:>3} {:<10}".format(t[0],round(t[1],2))

investment=float(input("Enter an initial investment."))
interest=float(input("Enter an interest rate between .01 to .10."))
years=int(input("Enter a number of years between 1 to 30."))

print(*list(map(formatInterest,enumerate([investment * (interest+1) ** i
                                          for i in range(years+1)]))),sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
  0 1000.0    
  1 1010.0    
  2 1020.1    
  3 1030.3    
  4 1040.6    
  5 1051.01   
  6 1061.52   
  7 1072.14   
  8 1082.86   
  9 1093.69   
 10 1104.62
```

You can read about map(), enumerate() and print() here:

- [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)
- [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
- [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

The list comprehension produces the values for each year, starting with 0 up to 10 (the input). The `enumerate` adds the year-number for the `formatInterest`-input-tuple. `map` applies the formatting and `print()` prints it all, using a `sep` of newline on the decomposed list.

Answer (score 1):

## Future Value Calculation

```
print("Investment Calculator")
print(f"=====================")
present_value = int(input("Principal Amount? "))
interest_rate = float(input("Annual Interest Rate? "))
terms_in_years = int(input("Number of Years? "))

future_value = present_value * pow((1 + (interest_rate / 100)), terms_in_years)
result = float("{:.2f}".format(future_value))

print(f"Future Value is: {result}")"
```